# Save my design automation output as a .zip file to keep the materials textures

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I am uploading a .zip file which consists of a Revit file and images to keep the textures of the materials, so how could I add the design automation output file to the same .zip file to keep the materials' textures?

Answer (score 0):

way 1: by Design Automation.
This blog tells how to create DA Activity that specifies the output as zip.
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-generate-dynamic-number-output-design-automation-revit-v3
While this assumes all the necessary files (images, updated revit file) will be available when DA makes the zip. you may need to define the activity with

- Input: also a zip, which provides the all files(images, source revit file). When DA starts to work, it will unzip them to the relative folder of working folder. It sounds you have done so.
- Output: a zip (as the blog mentions). When DA completes the job, it will package all contents of the relative folder. Finally send the zip to Forge Model Derivative API to translate to SVF (remember to specify the root file, and specify compressedUrn = true)

way 2: by yourself
Since you have the images , you can still define Design Automation Activity with single input and single output. While when the DA job completes, get the output revit file, and find the corresponding images and make the zip yourself. Finally send the zip to Forge Model Derivative API.
if with this way, you may need to build a map between revit file and its textures images.